# ReactiveMongo with Play: method gridFSBodyParser in trait MongoController is deprecated: Use `gridFSBodyParser` with `Future[GridFS]`

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, playframework-2.5

I have the following code in my controller in PlayFramework:

```
import reactivemongo.api.gridfs.GridFS
private val gridFS = reactiveMongoApi.gridFS

  def uploadLogo(companyId: String) = Action.async(gridFSBodyParser(gridFS))  { request =>
...
...
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
method gridFSBodyParser in trait MongoController is deprecated: Use gridFSBodyParser with Future[GridFS]
```

I tried changing the import `private val gridFS = reactiveMongoApi.gridFS` to `private val gridFS = reactiveMongoApi.asyncGridFS` but then I get an error as below:

```
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[reactivemongo.api.gridfs.GridFS[reactivemongo.play.json.JSONSerializationPack.type]]
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.gridfs.GridFS[reactivemongo.play.json.JSONSerializationPack.type]
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be better if you put version of reactive mongo and play that you are using.

Comment: These deprecation warnings are tagged for release 0.12.0, meanwhile function in Play 2.5.x BodyParsers to work with Future[BodyParser] will be restored (already on Play master). You can ignore deprecation warnings for 0.12.0 for now.